# How to pass the object as parameter to onClick method for html + js

Tags: javascript, html

I have found out the rover received from updateInfoFromRover is not readable. How can I pass the rover object inside the updateInfoFromRover method rather than split it into multiple strings like rover.image, rover.name and pass them one by one?

```js
// rovers = {name:..., image:...} multiple keys
const onClickButton = (rovers) => {
  return `${rovers.reduce(
    (acc, rover) =>
      acc +
      `<button onClick="updateInfoFromRover('${rover}')">${
        rover.name
      }</button>`,
    ""
  )}`;
};
const updateInfoFromRover = (rover) => {
  console.log("reach?", rover); //[object, object]
 if (rover != null && rover.img_src && rover.name) {
    return `<p>latest photo from ${rover.name} with launch date ${rover.launch_date} and landing date ${rover.landing_date}<img src="${rover.img_src}" height="350px" width="100%" />status ${rover.status}</p>`;
  }
};
```

```html
<div>${onClickButton(rovers)}</div>
```

Comment: In what way does that HTML even *invoke* the JavaScript function?  It seems like there's some info missing here...

Comment: Are you using some sort of library/framework?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your code is trying to achieve (kindly neaten it out) but I will try my best to offer a suitable solution. Also, kindly list any libraries or frameworks you are using for better and more suitable solutions.

```html
<div onclick="onClickButton(rovers)"></div>
```